# Not able to read XML Child node values in Java Script

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I am not able to read child node values. 
below is the XML i am trying to read. i wanted to read value of each child node.

```
 <vir-analysis version="2.9">
    <vehicle>
    <registration>
    <first-registration-date>16-Aug-1988</first-registration-date>
    <registration-status>Active</registration-status>
    <cause-of-last-registration>New</cause-of-last-registration>
    <registered-overseas>No</registered-overseas>
    <last-registration-date>16-Aug-1988</last-registration-date>
    </registration>

    <licence>
    <expiry-date value="2016-02-13">13-Feb-2016</expiry-date>
    <licence-type code="L">Licence</licence-type>
    <issue-date value="2015-01-15">15-Jan-2015</issue-date>
    </licence>

    <wof>
    <last-inspection-date>24-Feb-2015</last-inspection-date>
    <last-inspection-result code="P">Pass</last-inspection-result>
    <expiry-date value="2015-08-24">24-Aug-2015</expiry-date>
    </wof>   

    <cof>
    <is-subject-to value="false">No</is-subject-to>
    <expiry-date value="2015-08-24">24-Aug-2015</expiry-date>
    </cof>

    </vir-analysis>
```

Sample code with which i am trying to read values is as below, i am getting null values

**code:**

```
if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence").length!= 0){
    document.getElementById('LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE').value =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('LICENCE_TYPE').value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging what is `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0]`, `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[1]` ? (console.log())

Comment: Which browser do you use? Try using `textContent`.

Comment: @Justinas yes tried.. from that came to know its holding null value and not undefined

Comment: @Mouser tried on IE, Chrome and FireFox

Comment: @Vishal checked all properties to see in where value is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```js
if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence").length!= 0){
document.getElementById('LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE').value =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue; //a extra childnode is added to select the text node and display its content.
document.getElementById('LICENCE_TYPE').value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Or use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) like this:

```js
if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence").length!= 0){
document.getElementById('LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE').value =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[1].textContent;
document.getElementById('LICENCE_TYPE').value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("licence")[0].childNodes[2].textContent;
```

[`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) on an element will return `null`. However on a `text node` it will return the value. Since text is treated as a node you need to select another `childnode`. `textContent` gives you all the text inside the element.

Different node-types. Text inside a node is treated as a text-node. That's why nodeValue on the element returned `null`.
[image: Table from MDN]

Comment: Yes 2nd option giving value.. Thanks